# How to specify a location on appending a file

Tags: php, append

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
```

I want the testFile.txt to be located at the Desktop, and i perform this at C:/wamp/localhost/

How could state the location or can is it possible?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
$myFile = 'C:\Documents and Settings\<yourusername>\Desktop\testFile.txt';
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to say how to open your text file for append. then

```
$myFile = "YOUR_DESKTOP_PATH/testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
```